# How can I get the last 7 characters of a PHP string?

Tags: php, string

How would I go about grabbing the last 7 characters of the string below?

For example:

```
$dynamicstring = "2490slkj409slk5409els";
$newstring = some_function($dynamicstring);
echo "The new string is: " . $newstring;
```

Which would display:

```
The new string is: 5409els
```

Answer (score 808, accepted):

Use [`substr()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) with a negative number for the 2nd argument.

```
$newstring = substr($dynamicstring, -7);
```

From the [php docs](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

> `string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )`
>
> **If start is negative, the returned string will start at the start'th character from the end of string.**

Comment: But if $dynamicstring is less than 7 characters, $newstring will be empty. (at least on PHP 5.2.6)

Comment: You can always do a check with strlen first to see if the number of characters is greater than or equal to 7.

Comment: Since PHP 8 you could use `str_ends_with(string $haystack, string $needle): bool`

Answer (score 90):

umh.. like that?

```
$newstring = substr($dynamicstring, -7);
```

Answer (score 26):

It would be better to have a check before getting the string.

```
$newstring = substr($dynamicstring, -7);
```

if characters are greater then 7 return last 7 characters else return the provided string.

or do this if you need to return message or error if length is less then 7

```
$newstring = (strlen($dynamicstring)>=7)?substr($dynamicstring, -7):"message";
```

[substr documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: I think the else part is needed to give a message back. Something like invalid data entered or ..

Comment: This is probably the best answer, only thing that might make it better is a reference to the php manual.

Comment: In the second snippet, if strlen is **exactly** 7, it will return an error. FIX: Replace `>7` with `>=7`.

Answer (score 23):

Safer results for working with multibyte character codes, allways use mb_substr instead substr. Example for utf-8:

```
$str = 'Ne zaman seni düşünsem';
echo substr( $str, -7 ) . ' <strong>is not equal to</strong> ' .
  mb_substr( $str, -7, null, 'UTF-8') ;
```

Answer (score 6):

For simplicity, if you do not want send a message, try this

```
$new_string = substr( $dynamicstring, -min( strlen( $dynamicstring ), 7 ) );
```

Answer (score 5):

for last 7 characters

```
$newstring = substr($dynamicstring, -7);
```

$newstring : 5409els

for first 7 characters

```
$newstring = substr($dynamicstring, 0, 7);
```

$newstring : 2490slk

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers, unless you want to share new insights

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple correct answers here. But it isn't obvious what is needed, if you want a "safe" version of `substr`,

Same as `substr`, when the string is "long enough", but if the string is too short, return the original string (instead of returning `false`).

```
/** Unlike substr, handles case where $string is too short.
 * @param $string
 * @param $nChars - negative to return at end of string.
 */
function safe_substr($string, $nChars) {
    if ($nChars == 0 || !isset($string))
        return "";

    if (strlen($string) <= abs($nChars))
        // $string is too short (or exactly the desired length). Return the string.
        return $string;

    return substr($string, $nChars);
}
```

NOTE: FOR UTF-8 chars, define `safe_mb_substr`, replacing `substr` above with `mb_substr`. And replace `strlen` with `mb_strlen`.

Answer (score -4):

last 7 characters of a string:

```
$rest = substr( "abcdefghijklmnop", -7); // returns "jklmnop"
```

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers, unless you want to share new insights