# Removing first four charecters from a string using php based on multiple conditions

Tags: php, string

I need a help.. I need to check a string which have a differentcspecific pattern at its 0-5th position. and i need to remove that pattern from that position can u help me in this regard. I am a beginner on php.

For example.

1. if a number string like "009715012345" i need to crop 00971 from the first 5 position

2.if a number string like "+9715012345" i need to crop +971 from the first 5 position

3.if a number string like "97105012345" i need to crop 9710 from the first 4 position

want to check all condition. When it is inserting to database it should start from 5012345

Comment: but why dont you try to crop last 7 digits??? think logically

Comment: `$newstring = substr('009715012345', -7);` or `$newstring = substr('+97105012345', -7);` or `$newstring = substr('97105012345', -7);` same function for all requirements

Comment: Secondly, you already laid it out in pseudo code, you know what to do. Throw in some if statements (http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) and you should be golden. What do you need from SO, this website is not a replacement for documentation, practice and trying?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the last 7 characters of a PHP string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542310/how-can-i-get-the-last-7-characters-of-a-php-string)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `preg_replace` function.

```
$re = "/^(?:(?:\\+|00)971|9710)/m";
$str = "009715012345\n+9715012345\n97105012345";
$subst = "";
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result;
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bH6yT0/4)