# How can I get the last x characters of a string until I reach a specific character?

Tags: php, string

My questions is somewhat based off this:
[How can I get the last 7 characters of a PHP string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542310/how-can-i-get-the-last-7-characters-of-a-php-string)

Mine is similar. I need to get the last x characters of a string and to stop when I reach "-"

for example, I have a booking code:
N-903

and I can get the last 3 characters like so:

```
$booking_Code = N-903
$booking_Code = substr($booking_Code, -3);
```

and the result will be:

```
903
```

This number however will increase, so I expect to see booking codes like:

```
N-1001
N-22520
N-201548
```

so the code:

```
substr($booking_Code, -3);
```

would become useless. Is there any way to use "-" as a delimiter? I think that's the correct term to use. because the number that's generated will always come after the hyphen "-". Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: dont you just want to explode on the hyphen ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
<?php
$tmpArray = explode("-",$mystr);
echo $tmpArray[1];

?>
```

You might want to refer to [explode](http://php.net/explode) function in php.

Comment: I feel like an idiot now. Why did I not think of this!

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you could also use `strrchr` in conjunction with the `substr` you have:

```
$booking_Code = 'N-903';
$booking_Code = substr(strrchr($booking_Code, '-'), 1);
echo $booking_Code; // 903
```

Comment: I like this one too. Would this be applicable if I had multipl  hyphens in my string? e.g N-07-03-903
I would need the the digits after the last hyphen!

Comment: @AkiraDawson yes, that would be the beauty of it, you'd still get that last digits from the last `-`. `explode()` can cover that issue as well, just use `end()`. it'll get the last exploded element instead of pointing directly into the index