# Get "at most" last n characters from string using PHP substr?

Tags: php, substr

Answer of this question:

How can I get the last 7 characters of a PHP string? - Stack Overflow
[How can I get the last 7 characters of a PHP string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542310/how-can-i-get-the-last-7-characters-of-a-php-string)

shows this statement:

```
substr($s, -7)
```

However, if length of $s is smaller than 7, it will return empty string(tested on PHP 5.2.6), e.g.

```
substr("abcd", -4) returns "abcd"
substr("bcd", -4) returns nothing
```

Currently, my workaround is

```
trim(substr("   $s",-4)) // prepend 3 blanks
```

Is there another elegant way to write substr() so it can be more perfect?

====

EDIT: Sorry for the typo of return value of substr("bcd", -4) in my post. It  misguides people here. It  should return nothing. I already correct it. (@ 2016/1/29 17:03 GMT+8)

Comment: `substr( $s, ( strlen($s) >= 7 ? 7 : strlen($s) ) );`?

Comment: What output would you expect in your last example?

Comment: So what you want as an output?

Comment: I jst wish when I want to get last 4 but if there's not enough characters, the whole string will be return, i.e. what I write in the title "at most", not "exactly".

Comment: @ScottChu `substr("bcd", -4)` returns the whole string **bcd**. whats not working really?

Comment: I see axiac's answer. It's a bug. Thanks for each one of you who answered and commented.

Comment: do you mean sth like this `strlen($str) > 4 ? substr($str, -4) : $str;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
substr("abcd", -4) returns "abcd"
substr("bcd", -4) returns "bcd"
```

This is the correct behaviour of [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

There was a bug in the [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php#refsect1-function.substr-changelog) function in PHP versions 5.2.2-5.2.6 that made it return `FALSE` when its first argument (`start`) was negative and its absolute value was larger than the length of the string.

The behaviour is [documented](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php#refsect1-function.substr-changelog).

You should upgrade your PHP to a newer version (5.6 or 7.0). PHP 5.2 is [dead and buried](http://php.net/eol.php) more than 5 years ago.

Or, at least, upgrade PHP 5.2 to its latest release (5.2.17)

---

An elegant solution to your request (assuming you are locked with a faulty PHP version):

```
function substr52($string, $start, $length)
{
    $l = strlen($string);
    // Clamp $start and $length to the range [-$l, $l]
    // to circumvent the faulty behaviour in PHP 5.2.2-5.2.6
    $start  = min(max($start, -$l), $l);
    $length = min(max($start, -$l), $l);

    return substr($string, $start, $length);
}
```

However, it doesn't handle the cases when `$length` is `0`, `FALSE`, `NULL` or when it is omitted.

Answer (score 0):

In my haste with first comment I missed a parameter - I think it should have been more like this.

```
$s = 'look at all the thingymajigs';
echo trim( substr( $s, ( strlen( $s ) >= 7 ? -7 : -strlen( $s ) ), strlen( $s ) ) );
```